# How to execute .ktr file in linux with data parameters(another transformation)?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

As the question says, I would like to execute the .ktr file but via Linux

I tryied to execute `test.ktr` like this :

```
sh pan.sh -file="/path/to/test.ktr"
```

I got an error of :
 `Unable to get database metadata from this database connection, Error connecting to database [${DATABASE_NAME}]`

Before executing `test.ktr`, I have to execute `set_database_parameters.ktr` firstly, I have many transformations like `test.ktr`, that's the reason why I set a `set_database_parameters.ktr` file specially
it there a way to solve it? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a job to execute the transformations sequencially and execute the job, not the transformations separately

Comment: Can I only execute one transformation  without job?

Comment: There's the Transformation Executor step, but in this case it wouldn't work. Keep in mind that in a transformation all steps are started at the same time, so when your other steps are started needing the parameter values, they aren't set. No, you'll need a job to execute the transformations sequencially.